# how can I edit the value of a textview inside the listview through edittext which is also inside the listview?

Tags: android-listview

Here is my code. I have a textview and edittext inside the listview, can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance....

```
final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Viewer.this, viewnotes,
            R.layout.note_list, new String[] { "Id", "Notes", "Notes" },
            new int[] { R.id.noteid, R.id.listnote2, R.id.listnote });
    listnote.setAdapter(adapter);
    listnote.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                  EditText textnote = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.listnote2);  
                  notename1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listnote);
                  textnote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  notename1.setVisibility(View.GONE);


              }
            });

}
```

Comment: Whats t problem? there will be submit button or you can implimet editext ontextchangelistner on that just upadate the datastructure passed to adapter and notifydatasetchanged on adapter DONE!!

Comment: there is no button my friend. only edittext and textview. here is the scenario first the edittext is set to invisible only the textview is visible. if I click the item the edittext will appear in order to edit the value of a textview. help me my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the softkeybord done or enter like this and refresh the list

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView exampleView, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE 
            || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL
            || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

            //Do something in here
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: my friend, my listview is consist of many rows.. I want to edit every rows through clicking single row. But what happen is if I click into another row the first row which is supposed to be INVISIBLE, nothings happen. the output is two rows are now selected.